# C_cstringrefseqdistance and C_cstringdistance functions in TraMineR R package

Tags: c++, c, traminer

I cannot access the source codes for C_cstringrefseqdistance and C_cstringdistance C functions used by the seqdist() function in the TraMineR R package. Do you know if these source codes have been published or how I can retrieve it from the package?

Thanks in advance for your help, best,

t.

Answer (score 1):

The traminer package source is here https://github.com/cran/TraMineR

The functions you are looking for are in this source file: https://github.com/cran/TraMineR/blob/8db14382ec387d32470c21edd6f473217522c241/src/distancefunctions.cpp

Note the C_ prefix is R automagic, the C functions are actually `cstringrefseqdistance` and `cstringdistance`.

Comment: You also find the distancefunctions.cpp file in the src folder in the in the .tar.gz file available on the CRAN.